# Log out issue from second tab when log out from first tab in Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, access-token, session-storage

I am using sessionStorage to hold accessToken. My steps are as follows:-

- Login to website
- Click on duplicate option of tab. It will show the website in second tab.
- Log out from first tab.
- Expecting to logout from another tab when I refresh/hit any action on the second tab.

Actually it is not logging me out from another tab.

I added below code but it is not working as expected.

```
@HostListener('window:storage', ['$event'])
    onStorageChange(sv:StorageEvent) {       
      if(sv.storageArea == sessionStorage) 
      {
        let token = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        if(token == null || token == undefined)
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    }
```

Please let me know if I am doing any mistake. 
I am currently using this code in home page. Is it the right location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To communicate between tabs, you can make use of `localStorage` and still keep `sessionStorage` to store your sensitive data.

Here is a small implementation of an authentication service which uses:

- `sessionStorage` to store your user data (token or whatever)
- `localStorage` to communicate with other opened tabs.
- `rxjs` to trigger events from the service

The idea is that your application listens for storage events. Then when you sign out, it sets a flag in `localStorage`, which other opened tabs can capture.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject, Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})

export class AuthenticationService{

  private eventSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  public readonly statusChanged$: Observable<boolean> = this.eventSubject.asObservable();

  private loggedIn = false;

  constructor()
  {
    window.onstorage = () => { //
    {
      let loggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken') !== null;

      if(localStorage.getItem('signOut'))
      {
          loggedIn = false;
      }

      if(this.loggedIn !== loggedIn)//Don't trigger event if no change
      {
        this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
        this.eventSubject.next(loggedIn);
      }
    };
  }
}

  public logIn()
  {
    //Do your business to login and obtain a token before here...
    localStorage.removeItem('signOut');//clear flag in local storage
    sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', 'token');//save token in session storage
  }

  public logOut()
  {
    localStorage.setItem('signOut', 'true'); //trigger flag
    sessionStorage.removeItem('accessToken'); //Remove token from session
  }
  public isLoggedIn()
  {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }
}
```

You can just use that service in your components

```
constructor(private authSvc:AuthenticationService)
{
    this.authSvc.statusChanged$.subscribe(isLoggedIn=>
    {
      //Do whatever you want

    });
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kfsfnm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauthentication.service.ts).

Comment: Thanks for giving me an idea of keeping flag to track log in and log out events. It really worked well.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to place this code in the app.component.ts file

secondly  write a window event

```
 window.addEventListener('storage', (event) => {
            if (event.storageArea == localStorage) {
                let token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
                if (token == undefined) {
                    // Perform logout
                    //Navigate to login/home
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                }
            }
        });
```

I believe it should work fine

Comment: I have added above code inside ngOnInit() in app.component.ts file. Somehow this function never gets called when I logout from first tab.

Comment: @simpleuser how about you set the token inside localStorage and check it out, I will edit the above code accordingly.

Comment: Can you please help me with sessionStorage? Session Storage helped to logout automatically when browser is closed automatically.

Comment: @simpleuser the problem with sessionStorage is that it doesn't clear the records of other tabs, it will only clear the record on the tab in which you logged out of, whereas in localStorage it works for all tabs. So if you are worried of clearing local storage on the closing of browser, you can simply unload the page using the window.unload event. Here is the sample code:
`window.onunload = () => {
   // Clear the local storage
   window.localStorage.clear()
}`

Comment: Do you want to say that  "window.addEventListener('storage')" worked only for localStorage. I am asking this because when I put console.log("Hello") just after the function started then also it is not printing anything. My ask is that when should this function be invoked?

Answer (score 1):

Implement AuthGuard on your routes that require sign in. In the Auth Guard add your login check logic and if user is not logged in then redirect to sign in page.

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Router,CanActivate,ActivatedRouteSnapshot,RouterStateSnapshot} 
from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    if(!token)
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Your Routing file

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: YourComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
}]
```

I hope this works for you or anyone who's looking for the same solution. Thank you